Hardy space on a horizontal strip
Consider the classical Hardy-space $H^2(\mathbb{D})$ on the unit disc and the Hardy-space $H_\tau^2(\mathcal{S}):= \{ f\in \text{Hol}(\mathcal{S}) : \sup_{|y|<1} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(x+iy)|^2dx <\infty \}$ on the horizontal strip $\mathcal{S}:= \{z\in \mathbb{C} : |\text{Im}| <1 \}$. I was wondering if every $f\in H_\tau^2(\mathcal{S})$ is also in $H^2(\mathbb{D})$. I don't think it is, but what if we scale down the input, e.g. $g(z)=f(\frac{1}{2}z)$. Is then $g\in H^2(\mathbb{D})$?

The scaled function is certainly in $H^2(\mathbb{D})$. It is even in $H^\infty$ since it is bounded.

Could you elaborate on how I can see that?

Because $g$ is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is compact.

ah of course, thank you
